# React - invalid hook call. Uncaught Error: Minified React error #321

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I am trying to implement micro-frontend concept. For this I will have following `react` apps.

- Container
- Header
- Dashboard

All 3 are individual application. `Header` and `Dashboard` - I would like to use it in `Container` app.

For `Header` app, it's a simple `react` functional component. I am using following in `webpack.config.js`.

```
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
    filename: 'header-bundle.js',
    library: 'TestHeader',
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  },
```

In `package.json`:

```
"main": "dist/header-bundle.js",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "16.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.8.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.1"
  }
```

- Did `npm link` from `Header`

In `Container` app:
- `npm link Header`

In `App.js` component of `Container`:

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from 'header-app';

const App = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header content="Header via container"></Header>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

This works fine.

But when I add `Dashboard` component which uses `react hooks`, I am getting an error about invalid hook call.

`Dashboard` app also has `react` as `peerDependencies`. Individually `Dashboard` app works fine.

`Dashboard` component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import NoIcon from './no_icon.png';

const Card = props => {
  return (
    <div style={{ margin: '1em' }}>
      <img alt="avatar" style={{ width: '70px' }} src={NoIcon} />
      <div>
        <div style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{props.label}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const CardList = props => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: 'grid',
        gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(3, auto)'
      }}
    >
      {props.cards.map(card => (
        <Card {...card} key={card.id} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const Dashboard = props => {
  // const { apps } = props;
  const [hasError, setErrors] = useState(false);
  const [apps, setApps] = useState([]);

  async function fetchData() {
    const res = await fetch('src/data.json');
    res
      .json()
      .then(res => setApps(res))
      .catch(err => setErrors(err));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <CardList cards={apps} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

I've few questions here:

- **How can I use multiple `react` apps in one `react` app?**
- **Exporting a whole `react` app as a single component as `umd` library and use it in another app is correct way?**
- **How can I resolve this error of `react` hooks? How does `react` as `peerDependencies` work in a library and in application where it is being used?**

Answer (score 1):

> How can I use multiple react apps in one react app?

You did so correctly. Each react app is packaged individually then imported where they are needed.

> Exporting a whole react app as a single component as umd library and use it in another app is correct way?

This is one way yes.

> How does react as peerDependencies work in a library and in application where it is being used?

`peerDependencies` allow you to state which library and version should already be installed before the package is installed.

For example when you write this in the package.json for Header

```
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "16.12.0"
  },
```

You are saying that the Container app should have `react@16.12.0` in order to work with Header.
The same peer dependency should be added to the Dashboard.

> How can I resolve this error of react hooks?

Since you didn't include the error message, I'm assuming you're referring to the error where a hook should not be called conditionally. In order to fix that error, we'd need to have a minimal reproduction of your application so we can test it. There is not much to go off in your example.